# Function execution is not in order react native

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native, react-navigation

I am using react-navigation for navigating through screens. I have the following button tag with an `onPress` property where if it is pressed, `navigate` will be called and it should go to the `Downloading` Screen. After that, call, `generateReports()` function, passing a callback function.

```
<Button transparent onPress={() => {
          navigate('Downloading')
          generateReports(() => navigate('Home'))
        }}>

export const generateReports = (callback) => {
  generateReportsTable(callback)
}

export const generateReportsTable = (callback) => {
  let currentYear = new Date(new Date().getFullYear(), 0, 1);
  let organizations = realm.objects('Organization')
  let tickets = realm.objects('Ticket')
  let currentYearTickets = tickets.filtered('created_at > $0', new 
Date(currentYear).getTime())
   for(organization of organizations) {
    let currentOrganizationTickets = []
    console.log(organization.name)
    for(ticket of currentYearTickets) {
      if(ticket.organization_id === organization.id) {
         currentOrganizationTickets.push(ticket)
      }
    }
    console.log(currentOrganizationTickets)
  }
  callback()
}
```

However, when I run the code, and the button is pressed, the app hangs until the process of `generateReports` finishes and does the navigating. What am I missing? I need to navigate first, then execute `generateReports()`

Comment: What is the code in `initiateDownload`? Sound like it's freezing your JS thread

Comment: Hi @MotiAzu. I have some code for downloading data through API.

Comment: Please share that code with us so we can help

Comment: Edited the post @MotiAzu. Thanks